# Why does echo $'\n' print 2 new lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to learn shell scripting and I came across [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html). I understand that backlash escaped sequences will be decoded by the ANSI-C standard. According to the link, `echo $'\n'` should print a single new-line character. I am unable to understand why `echo $'\n'` prints 2 new-line characters?

Comment: For the ANSI-C Quoting thing --- I learn something every day

Answer (score 5):

Let's turn to some documentation:

From [posix echo](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/echo.html):

> The echo utility writes its arguments to standard output, followed by a <newline>.

There is one argument given to `echo`. The argument is a `$'\n'` - which is decoded as a newline. So `echo` prints it's argument  - a newline - followed by a newline - so two newlines in total.

Comment: At least with Gnu echo, the `-n` argument can be given to suppress the final newline. http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html

Comment: @erichamion /bin/echo is generally overridden by a shell builtin (in both bash and zsh), which might or might not take `-n` to suppress the final newline (in bash, it can depend on both compile- and run-time options). It's a hopeless mess. If you want to *reliably* print things without adding a newline, use `printf "%s" "stringtoprint"`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `echo` writes the output with a trailing newline character.

If you do an `strace`, you can see this in the `write` system call:-

```
$ strace -e write echo $'\n'
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
```

As per the manual, you can suppress this using a `-n` switch:-

```
$ strace -e write echo -n $'\n'
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
```